# Does JVM create Objects of primitive types at runtime in java?

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive-types

It may be a stupid question but as i was going to create a arithmetic exception case i.e 44/0 ... i created this below program

```
public class Simple{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    float a = 78.0f;
    float b= 0.0f;
    float c= a/b;
    System.out.println(c);
  }
}
```

Result :

```
Infinity
```

But the Positive Infinity is a final static field in the Float Wrapper class. So does that means that every primitive is autoboxed to wrapper class object at runtime? If not , then how came it returned infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY) is a static field on the `Float` class, true. But it is of type `float` (not `Float`), so it is itself a primitive. No boxing is happening here.

The fact of the matter is that a `float`, being an [IEEE 754 single-precision floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), cannot just hold a range of regular floating-point numbers, but also a few special values, like ±∞ and NaN. And because Java doesn't have special syntax to write these values, they are offered as static fields on the `Float` class instead.

Comment: Aww thanks .. I notice that its type is float but i was confused that how it is going to hold that value.. Thanks much appreciated. will accept your answer in 4 minutes :)